# Is "nor does it to human" an reasonably condensed version of "nor does it make sense to human"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, expressions

This [post](https://pawelmhm.github.io/python/static/typing/type/annotations/2016/01/23/typing-python3.html) says

> It may be a pain to see compile errors, but trust me, getting error here is good for you. You did something stupid you tried to compare string with int and decide which one is equal. This does not make any sense to the computer most of the time (**nor does it make sense to human**), so you should never be able to run program like this. Computer says “No!” and you have to cope with that.

In which, "nor does it make sense to human" seems to be redundant, is this one more appropriate, "nor does it to human"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many errors in the text you quoted; it is obviously not written by a native English speaker. However, the answer to your question would be "yes", except that it needs to be "nor does it to **a human**", or "nor does it to **humans**".

Comment: That should be "humans". Thanks a lot! In contrast to "nor does it to humans", is  "nor does it to human beings" more idiomatic?

Comment: 'humans' is a commonly used shorter alternative to 'human beings' and is the more idiomatic.